# What mechanic can I use to order an array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am stuck at a very weird problem. I mean I do not how to threat this.

Basically, I got a webpage where I list all stops for a defined bus route (example, `route_id = 141`). Sometime, a route, can start from point A and go to point B so theoretically from one terminus to another terminus. BUT, sometime, the same route can begin its trip somewhere between A and B and go at point A or B.

You can see a live working example at this address : http://stm.tranzit.ca/bus/stops/85/Hochelaga/

My super draw :

```
Regular trip
Start(A) ----------------------------------- End(B)

Sometime
                 Start --------------------- End(B)
Start(A) ---------------------- End
```

etc.. Its always going to be between point A and B. 90% of the time it's from A to B but the other 10% it can be anywhere between there until another point between there (sometime is from middle to A or B).

Ok. Before I was sorting my result using stop_sequence. I know the order of the stop sequence, so stop 1, stop 2, etc and how many stop by trip (a trip is from A to B, or A to middle, etc).

Now, I found a way to sort my result by trip and distinct them so now I know all the trip I got (A-B, B-A, A-middle, middle-B, etc..).

So if let's say I got A-B, B-A, A-Middle and B-Middle, I have 4 possibles trips for a route. I then fetch all stop linked to it.

Example, this is a list for trip A to B for a defined route. Please note the value at stop_sequence 35.

```
1   #53014  Station Frontenac (Frontenac / Ontario)

... 2, 3. etc..

34  #53293  Honoré-Beaugrand / Roux  
35  #54257  Station Honoré-Beaugrand / Sherbrooke    
36  #53290  Saint-Donat / Sherbrooke     
37  #53265  Saint-Donat / De Forbin-Janson   
38  #54676  Saint-Donat / De Grosbois    
39  #54674  Saint-Donat / Roi-René   
40  #54672  Saint-Donat / les Reaux  
41  #54668  Saint-Donat / Chénier    
42  #54661  Joseph-Renaud / Yves-Prévost     
43  #54646  Joseph-Renaud / Châtillon    
44  #54629  Joseph-Renaud / Wilfrid-Pelletier    
45  #54605  Joseph-Renaud / Châteauneuf  
46  #54609  Châteauneuf / Vaujours   
47  #54610  Châteauneuf / Rabelais   
48  #54612  Châteauneuf / de la Loire    
49  #54621  Châteauneuf / Roi-René   
50  #54623  Châteauneuf / des Ormeaux    
51  #54639  Châteauneuf / Rondeau    
52  #54724  Rondeau / Georges    
53  #54735  Rondeau / De La Vérendrye    
54  #54738  Rhéaume / Chaumont   
55  #54740  Chaumont / Guy   
56  #54741  Chaumont / Azilda    
57  #54742  Yves-Prévost / Azilda    
58  #54659  des Ormeaux / Chaumont
```

Here's a trip between middle and B.

```
1   #54257  Station Honoré-Beaugrand / Sherbrooke    
2   #53290  Saint-Donat / Sherbrooke     
3   #53265  Saint-Donat / De Forbin-Janson   
4   #54676  Saint-Donat / De Grosbois    
5   #54674  Saint-Donat / Roi-René   
6   #54672  Saint-Donat / les Reaux  
7   #54668  Saint-Donat / Chénier    
8   #54661  Joseph-Renaud / Yves-Prévost     
9   #54646  Joseph-Renaud / Châtillon    
10  #54629  Joseph-Renaud / Wilfrid-Pelletier    
11  #54605  Joseph-Renaud / Châteauneuf  
12  #54609  Châteauneuf / Vaujours   
13  #54610  Châteauneuf / Rabelais   
14  #54612  Châteauneuf / de la Loire    
15  #54621  Châteauneuf / Roi-René   
16  #54623  Châteauneuf / des Ormeaux    
17  #54639  Châteauneuf / Rondeau    
18  #54724  Rondeau / Georges    
19  #54735  Rondeau / De La Vérendrye    
20  #54738  Rhéaume / Chaumont   
21  #54740  Chaumont / Guy   
22  #54741  Chaumont / Azilda    
23  #54742  Yves-Prévost / Azilda    
24  #54659  des Ormeaux / Chaumont
```

Now, as you can see, stop_sequence 1 here is the same as 35. Second stop is the same as stop 36 above. As you can see also, the count from stop 35 to 58 is 24. The same as the second trip.

Now, what I want to know, is how I can merge them using PHP ? I would like to take let's say second group here and merge it inside the first one at the first occurence that match, so stop_sequence 1 from second group will become stop_sequence 35 because it match and it is the same.

Using this way, I can keep the stop order, not by using stop_sequence at the end of ordering, because as you saw, the second trip has stop_sequence 1 equal to 24 on the first trip. It mean that if I order by stop_sequence using MySQL, it will order sequentially all stop_sequence so the resulst will be stop_sequence 1 from first trip, sequence 1 from second trip, etc and my order will be wrong of all stops will be cleary wrong.

I want to do this in PHP but I do not know how to match result in an array and avoid X result after so I can match perfectly.

If you want to know what is my SQL query, here it is :

```
SELECT      t.trip_id, t.trip_headsign, st.stop_sequence, s.stop_id, s.stop_code, s.stop_name
FROM        trips AS t
LEFT JOIN   stop_times AS st ON st.trip_id = t.trip_id
LEFT JOIN   stops AS s ON s.stop_id = st.stop_id
WHERE       t.route_id = 141
    AND     t.trip_id IN (
        SELECT trip_id
        FROM (
            SELECT trip_id
            FROM (
                SELECT      COUNT(*) AS count, trips.trip_id, trips.trip_headsign
                FROM        trips
                LEFT JOIN   stop_times ON trips.trip_id = stop_times.trip_id
                WHERE       route_id = 141
                    AND     trips.trip_id LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(service_id, "%") FROM calendar_dates WHERE date = "20120628")
                GROUP BY    trips.trip_id
            ) a
            GROUP BY count, trip_headsign
        ) a
    )
GROUP BY    t.trip_id, st.stop_id
ORDER BY    t.trip_id ASC, st.stop_sequence ASC
```

`trip_id` define if it's from A-B, B-A, A-middle, etc.

`stop_sequence` is the order of the stop for a defined trip

`stop_id` and `stop_code` share the same thing - unique id (one for user and one for the internal system)

`trip_headsign` is like 141-W or 141-N (as for west or north).!

**EDIT**:

With my query, I can get all stop for each trip (green and red here).
I want to merge this in one list by keeping the order.
[example schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziQ4N.png)

Route can be from stop 1 (red) to stop 8. So trip 1 can be stop 1, stop 2, etc until stop 8.

Route can be from stop 1 (green) to stop 8. So trip can be stop 1, stop 7 and stop 8.

My query give me both trip stop's list.

Now, I want to merge them as follow :

List:
- Stop 1 (red)
- Stop 2
- Stop 3
....
- Stop 6
- Stop 1 (green)
- Stop 7 (once even if he is in trip red and green)
- Stop 8 (once even if he is in trip red and green)

Comment: Your query gives you multiple trips for that route right? And you wish to "align" the shorter trips to the longer ones?

Comment: @Jack This query will return all stop grouped by trip. So let's say I got trip A to B, middle to B and B to A, it will return all stop in the good sequence for each trip. If we consider this query with the above example, the above example return 2 trips (A-B and middle to B). I'd like to merge B into A BECAUSE B match a part of it. So in the end, the order is kept and I don't have multiple list. Just one list.

Comment: Wait, can't you just keep the longest trip in terms of number of stops? Wouldn't that always be the right one?

Comment: @Jack I could, but sometime a trip who start in the middle to B (example) can start from an unknow stop in the trip A-B as first stop, but second stop will be in the first trip. Let's say you take the bus at the street Jack / David, the trip start there. And then the bus go to Jack / 13e avenue and Jack / 15e avenue. Alright you got 3 stops. Let's say another trip start at David / 13e avenue then go to Jack / 13e Avenue and continue the regular trip. How can I handle that to insert David / 13e just after Jack / David and merge the rest ?

Comment: @Jack Check my edit, I add a schema

Comment: If that's the case, how should that trip be merged? Should the unknown stop be included in the final result? If not, how is it different from just choosing the longest trip as the final result? Unless, of course, the unknown part of a trip is in fact longer than the result you want

Comment: @Jack Because sometime a trip will have 1 or 2 stops who's not included inside the longest trip. I need to insert them where they belong inside the list (longest trip let's say). So if they come after stop 37 but this stop aint in the longest trip, it need to be stop 37, the "new" stop, stop 38, etc.

Comment: Check http://stm.tranzit.ca/bus/stops/449/Express-Rivire-des-Prairies/ . As you can see in the first table, trip goes from 1 to 41 (end at #54243). But in the second and third table, he trip start and end at the same place but has different stop.

Comment: If the stops that are not between A and B should be merged into the result, I don't see how that would become a single list. Rather I would imagine two lists (side by side) that are aligned to each other.

Comment: @Jack That's not a bad idea. I just need to find a way to distinct them.

Comment: The first idea I had was to just check if the first stop is A; if so it's "left aligned". If the last stop is B, it's "right aligned". If first stop is A and last stop is B, then that's what the alignment should be based on

Comment: So I check the longest trip from A to B and B to A and make them on two separate rows. I then take the others trips and by using the first or last stop, i assign them to row 1 or row 2 and print them on the right of the longest trip. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Not just the longest trip, the trip would have to start at A and end at B to be called "THE trip" :)

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks, I was looking for the wrong thing to do. Sometime the easier way is the best as we can see ! If you want the rep, make an answer for it, will be my pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize what has been said in the comments:

1. Find the authoritative trip by asserting the first stop is A and the last stop is B
2. For each other trip:

   1. if the first stop is A, it will be left / top aligned to the main trip
   2. if the last stop is B, it will be right / bottom aligned to the main trip

Optionally, you can start on either side of the shorter trip and remove any stops that don't appear in the main trip.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your precious time.

Comment: @DavidBélanger my pleasure; glad I could still wrap my head around the problem in the end :)

Comment: Yea, it is not easy. I use GTFS database and Google did this to make this hard to work with.